# 404 with j_spring_security_check on deploying with maven

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, maven-2, jstl

I am working on a project that has `spring` and `maven`, When i run it using eclipse `run on server` everything works fine. But when I do `maven install` and `deploy` the application on `tomcat`. It shows the login page which i right, but when i submit the login form. I get `404` with `url` `myWebApp/j_spring_security_check`.

I have tried every thing i could find on the topic, that has been of no help.

I am adding my `web.xml`, `applicationContext.xml`, `spring-security.xml`, `login-page.jsp` and `pom.xml` with the question

**`web.xml`**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>myApp-v1.0</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>types</param-name>
        <param-value>Single-Select</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>typeIds</param-name>
        <param-value>scq</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>rangeSeparator</param-name>
        <param-value>-</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Question shold be given to user for user information  -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>userInformationQuestion</param-name>
        <param-value>Please fill following information for better search result.</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Answer shold be given to user for user information  -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>userInformationAnswers</param-name>
        <param-value>Age,Gender,Profession</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
             <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
             <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/classes/spring-security.xml
                    /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
             </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Processes application requests -->



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>itemSearch</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/item-search.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>itemSearch</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ItemSearch</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/login-page.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>itemType</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/item-type.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>itemType</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ItemType</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.psd</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>




    <welcome-file-list> 

        <welcome-file> /item-search.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

**`applicationContext.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.myApp.util.ApplicationContextProvider" />
    <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myApp" />

    <bean id="meassageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/classes/message/message_en.properties"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    </bean>
    <bean id="rangeSeparator" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${rangeSeparator}"/>
    </bean> 
    <!--  -->

    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"></bean>
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.myApp.auth.service.MyAppUserDetailsService"/>
    <bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myAppDb"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="5"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="mysql"/>
  </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >

        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />
        </bean>


</beans>
```

**`spring-security.xml`**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/item-search.jsp" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/ItemSearch" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/ItemType" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/DecisionTree" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/CustomAttribute" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/ItemSearch" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <remember-me 
            user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
            token-validity-seconds="1209600"
            remember-me-parameter="remember-me"
            data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>


    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider">

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**`login-page.jsp`**

```
<!doctype html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Login | Page</title>

<!-- fab icon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/myApp/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/toolTip.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />-->
<script src="http://wcetdesigns.com/assets/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://wcetdesigns.com/assets/javascript/jquery/cookie-plugin.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="loginbg" >
    <div class="col-lg-12 login_header">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 logindiv effect2">
        <div class="container-fluid login_title">               
            <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid login_body">
            <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl"/>

            <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" class="login_form"  action="${loginUrl}" method='POST'>
                <div class="form_elements">
                    <span class="formicons username"></span>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="login-user_name" placeholder="Email ID" class="gradient_glossy" />
                </div>
                <div class="form_elements">
                    <span class="formicons password"></span>
                    <input type="password" id="login_user_password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="gradient_glossy" />
                </div>
                <div class="form_elements" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                    <div class="form_left">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="chkLoginRrememberMe"/> Remember Me
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_right">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="login_error_message" style="display:none">
                    <p id="error_msg_para"></p>
                </div>
                <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $("#error_msg_para").text("Invalid username or password!");
                        $("#login_error_message").show();
                    </script>   
                </c:if>
                <div class="form_elements">
                    <button type="button" id="btnLoginSubmit" class="login_btn btn gradient_brown" name="submit" onclick="javascript:formSubmit()"> Login</button>              <div id='result'></div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <script>
                    function formSubmit() {
                        var username = $("#login-user_name").val();
                        var password = $("#login-user_password").val();
                        if(username === "" || password === ""){
                            $("#error_msg_para").text("Username or password can not be left empty!");
                            $("#login_error_message").show();
                        }
                        else if(username.indexOf("@")==-1 || username.indexOf(".com")==-1){
                            $("#error_msg_para").text("Invalid username format!");
                            $("#login_error_message").show();
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#btnLoginSubmit").attr('type','submit');
                            document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
                        }
                    }
                </script>

        </div>
    </div>      

</body>
</html>
```

**`pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>v1.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <name>MyApp</name>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>


          <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.17</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>20040616</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- JSTL taglib -->
      <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just that in `web.xml`. I had put `/rest/*` for mapping the `appServlet` and It was applied to all calls, after replacing the `/rest/*` with `/*` the application is working perfect.